# Facebook: confirm mobile app ownership is not display

Tags: facebook, ads

in the facebook developer page,after add new app , and add google play platform,and fill the mandatory fields.but still there is no  [confirm mobile app ownership] section show.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Arjwm.jpg)
any any know the issue?

I have ad the app to my business account to have permission to manage it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnxCE.jpg)